# d3js: mouseover with object context (function pointer)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I tried to write a `Graph` class in JavaScript which I want to use as base for further graphs on my website. My problem is the mousedown-Handler:

The `Graph` constructor of the class adds the mousedown-Method:

```
this.test = "hello world!";
this.svg.on("mousedown", this.mousedown);
// this.svg.on("mousedown", Graph.prototype.mousedown); <-- does the same
```

Whereas the method looks like this:

```
Graph.prototype.mousedown = function() {
    alert(this.test);
};
```

The problem now it, that this method is not called inside the `Graph` context, instead, it is a reference to `g.[object SVGAnimatedString]`. It seems that not the actual method `Graph.prototype.mousedown` gets called.

Is there any way to achieve what I intend to do here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common problem in JavaScript, not unique to D3 (you can google stuff like "javascript function this object scope" to read more). Specifically in this case, d3 is explicitly setting the `this` object (aka context) to be the html or svg element associated with the mousedown event. It does the same thing in several other cases, such as inside the `attr` and `style` methods. This is considered a useful feature of d3, because it combines for you the html element and its associated data. It does mean, as you've discovered, that there is a `this` conflict when you pass into a d3 method a class instance method, which is partially why you don't commonly see d3 examples using this style of class construction (ie making use of `prototype` and `this`).

You can still work around it though, by assigning your `this` (the instance of Graph) to a variable declared outside a closure (and again, this is a general JavaScript technique, not a d3 thing):

```
// _this is the instance of your class
_this = this;

// _this inside this closure will continue to point to your Graph instance
this.svg.on("mousedown", function(d, i) { _this.mousedown(d, i) });
```

Note that as a result of this you'll no longer have access to the associated html/svg element from inside your mousedown method, which is ok if you don't need it. Otherwise you have to pass it in as a 3rd param to your mousedown function: `_this.mousedown(d, i, this)`.

Also, this style gets tedious after a while if you're doing it in a lot of places. If so, you might consider switching to defining your classes differently -- without the reliance on `prototype` and `this`. Most naturally, you may want to do it the way d3 objects are implemented. You can get more info by checking out the d3 source code (look for `d3.svg.axis` for one such example).

Comment: Sir, you are my saviour! Thank you very much I've been struggling with this for hours!