# Reference backbone functions from within a nested d3 function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, d3.js

I am trying to reference a backbone function from within a d3 function inside the backbone `render` function.  I now must reference other Backbone functions, to do some backboney things, but can't access them by referencing it by using the this/that method (I use this/ƒthis):

```
define([
  // this is for require.js file modularization 
], function(){
  return Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(options){
      //CODE
      this.render();
    },

    render: function(options){
      // HOW I ACCESS THE BACKBONE VIEW IN NESTED SITUATIONS
      var ƒthis = this;    

      //NORMAL RENDERING
      if (!options) {        
        // Do some stuff, get some vars

        // compile the template

        // D3 stuff
        var lineData = ({...});
        var pathFunction = d3.svg.line()
        var beatUnwindingPaths = [......];

        var beatContainer = d3.select('#beatHolder'+this.parent.cid);
        var beatPath = beatContainer //.append('g')
            .insert('path', ':first-child')
            .data([beatUnwindingPaths[0]])
            .attr('d', pathFunction)
            .attr('class', 'beat')
   //THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO REFERENCE THE FUNCTION TO BE CALLED, AND HOW I THINK IT SHOULD BE CALLED
            .on('click', ƒthis.toggle);
   //BUT CURRENTLY I AM ONLY LIMITED TO CALLING A FUNCTION DECLARED WITHIN THE BACKBONE render func(), so it would look like this:
            .on('click', toggle);

   //CURRENTLY I AM HAVING TO DECLARE THE FUNCTIONS INSIDE RENDER
        function unroll() {
          //do some stuff
        };
        function reverse() {
        };
        $('#a').on('click', unroll);
        $('#b').on('click', reverse);
      }
    },

// THIS IS THE FUNCTION I WANT TO CALL
    toggle: function(){
       //DO some stuff to the other BackBone models, collections and other cool stuff
    }
  });
});
```

How do I access the Backbone `toggle` function from inside the D3 code?

Error code is from within the toggle function itself (worked before, so I am trying to figure out why it isn't now), and the error is on 313, not 314, my browser console always is one line off.    I put a console.log() to see that with the ƒthis.toggle I got in the function, but error-ed out on the switching of the bool value.

```
311 toggle: function(){
312   //switch the selected boolean value on the model
313   this.model.set('selected', !this.model.get('selected'));
314   //re-render it, passing the clicked beat to render()
315   this.render(this.model);
316   // log.sendLog([[1, "beat" + this.model.cid + " toggled: "+!bool]]);
317   dispatch.trigger('beatClicked.event');
318 }
```

I switched from the rendering the circle in the template, to having d3 create it (so we could animate it using the d3 functions), and I think somehow the object has lost its binding to the model.   Working on this.....

Comment: you've already answered your question - you saved a reference to this with fthis, and you use fthis to reference the toggle function defined on the view object

Comment: @kinakuta actually, he doesn't even need the `fthis`. It's not an asynchronous call, so `fthis.toggle` will be evaluted directly. The only thing I see here that could be wrong is the context when the `toggle` method is called.

Comment: `ƒthis.toggle` isnt working, get the anonymous function error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined beatView.js:314
Backbone.View.extend.toggle beatView.js:314
(anonymous function)` which points to d3 as the culprit: `function d3_selection_onListener(listener, argumentz) {
    return function(e) {
      var o = d3.event;
      d3.event = e;
      argumentz[0] = this.__data__;
      try {listener.apply(this, argumentz);} finally {d3.event = o;}};}`

Comment: hrm,   it seems that there might be a problem with the function itself,  looking into whether it is or not.

Comment: @Loamhoof Can you explain, or link to the asynchronous call, that you are talking about? and the explain the context as well?

Comment: That'd be rather long. It's just understanding when the JS call is evaluated. To keep it simple, anything outside a function is evaluated directly when "read". So here, in your `.on('click', ƒthis.toggle);`, `ƒthis.toggle` will directly be replaced by the function itself, as if you had put `this.toggle`. If you had done it like `function() {ƒthis.toggle();}` instead, the call to `toggle` would have been inside a function and therefore would have needed the `ƒthis` because the context (the "this") would not have been the same when the function would have been evaluated.

Comment: As for the problem, what is the 314th line? It'd help to know that :)

Comment: @chrisFrisina Here's the answer to a nearly identical problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16656680/d3js-mouseover-with-object-context-function-pointer/16658817#16658817

Comment: See *nrabinowitz*'s answer, as it was indeed a context problem. Just FYI, there's also a native JS solution to bind the context which is the function's `bind` method: `on('click', this.toggle.bind(this))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a D3/Backbone issue, it's just Javascript. You can't pass an object method to be invoked later and expect `this` to work within that method unless you bind it in one way or another:

```
var myObject = {
    method: function() {
        this.doSomeStuff();
    },
    doSomeStuff: function() {
        console.log("stuff!");
    }
};

myObject.method(); // "stuff!"

// pass this method somewhere else - this is
// effectively what you do with an event handler
var myMethod = myObject.method;

myMethod(); // TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'doSomeStuff'
```

The second part fails because the invocation `myObject.myMethod()` binds `this` to `myObject`, but assigning the method to a variable (or assigning it as an event handler) does not (in most cases, `this` is bound to `window`, but D3 will reassign `this` to the DOM element you set the handler on).

The standard fixes are 1) wrapping it in a function:

```
var myMethod = function() {
    myObject.method();
};

myMethod();  // "stuff!"
```

or 2) binding it to the object somehow, e.g. in your Backbone `initialize` method (Underscore provides a useful `_.bindAll` utility for this purpose):

```
Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(options){
        _.bindAll(this, 'toggle');
        // now you can pass this.toggle around with impunity
    },
    // ...
});
```